# How do I print a rich text file from a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell to automate some tasks, and I've worked out how to edit a .rtf file template and save this back to disk using `$content | Set-Output $fileName`

This generates a brilliant looking rtf file, complete with bolds, italics, alignment etc.

I'd now like to automatically print this file to the default printer, which is installed with the correct drivers on the machine running the script.

I'm doing this using `$content | Out-Printer`, but this produces what I presume is the plaintext encoding of the rtf file, rather than the actual formatted document.

Is there any way to print a rtf file *with* the correct formatting, or am I doomed to plaintext for eternity?

Answer (score 0):

If your `.rtf` files have a `Print` option in their context menu, that can be invoked in **PowerShell** using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2) with the [`-FilePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2#-filepath) and [`-Verb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2#-verb) parameters. In its simplest form:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\rtfFiles\SomeFile.rtf' -Verb Print
```

And of course, in real life, the path will most likely be contained in a variable and the Cmdlet inside a loop:

```
Get-ChildItem *.rtf | ForEach{
    Start-Process -FilePath $_.FullName -Verb Print
}
```